# Finding the dimension of Null space of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Consider a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^3$ given by:
>
> $T(x,y, z) = (x - y, x -y,0)$
>
> If $N(T)$ and $R(T)$ denote the null space and range space of $T$ respectively, then
> find the dimension of $N(T)$ and $R(T)$. Check that $N(T) \subset R(T)$ or not?

> **My approach** $N(T)= \{(x, y, z):(x - y, x -y,0)= (0, 0, 0)\}$

Thus $x-y=0$, dimension of solution of this linear system is $n- r = 3-1 = 2$, where $n$ is the number of unknowns (x, y, z) and $r$ is the rank of matrix $(1, -1, 0)$. By Rank-Nullity theorem $rank(T) = 1$. Thus $N(T) \subset R(T)$ is not possible.
If there is any other approach to solve this problem kindly write.

Thank you so much

Comment: Your approach is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your method is good, and you even don't need to find null space for $T$, because

$R(T)=(x-y)\cdot(1,1,0)=span\{(1,1,0)\}$

So we get $\dim R(T)=1$, by rank theorem, $\dim N(T)=2$, so it is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to find $T$ as a matrix; which is
$T=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\1&-1&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$
$\because rank(T)=1=dim(R(T))$
$\therefore$ $nullity(T)=(number\ of\ columns)-1=3-1=2=dim(N(T)$.
This suggests $N(T)\not\subset R(T)$.